# Create a partition from a directory

Tags: partition, directory, hard-disk

I have a Linux system with only one partition `/dev/sda1` on `/dev/sda` disk with `/` mount point. Is it possible to create partitions after installation?

e.g. create `/dev/sda2` with the mount point `/home/`

How can I achieve it from command line? How is it physically implemented? (If I later remove `/dev/sda1` will it remove my `/home/` directory because it's a subdirectory of `/`? I'd like this partition to survive and I could install new system someday.

Comment: If you do this much, I suggest using LVM, which does make this a little more pleasant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a new partition in an already partitioned system you should start with a livecd, then use `gparted` to shrink the `sda1` partition (that I assume takes all the space on the disk, excluded the swap), then create a new partition in the free space created.

It can be of course done on the command line, but *GParted* takes care of many details that are difficult to track.

After creating the partition, you should move the content of your current home on the new partition, then modify `/etc/fstab` to mount the new partition on `/home`.

Here's one way to actually move the files from sda1 to sda2. All this is done as root:

1. Take a backup. Have you tried restoring your backups? They're not backups until you do. And make sure that they're stored on a different machine (that isn't mounted), or on an external drive that is *currently detached*. The point is, `rm -Rf /` shouldn't delete them. Nor should `mkfs` on the wrong partition.
2. Read all the steps and make sure you fully understand them before starting. Except for take a backup. You should do that immediately if you haven't already.
3. Make a filesystem on sda2. Something like `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2` (assuming you're fine with ext4, which is probably what you're currently using on sda1).
4. Mount `sda2` to somewhere that isn't /home. For example, you could `mkdir /mnt/new_home` and then `mount -text4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/new_home`
5. Make sure no users are logged in—otherwise they may be trying to change their files as you do this.
6. Copy the files. First, confirm that /home doesn't have anything hidden (only dot entries should be `.` and `..`) by doing `ls -l /home`. If it does, you need to copy the separately (`*` will not match them, and `.*` doesn't do what you want): `cp -a /home/* /mnt/new_home/`
7. Stop now if there are any errors copying.
8. Unmount sda2: `umount /mnt/new_home`. Do it now to make sure you don't accidentally nuke the wrong one.
9. This is the point of no return. `rm -Rf /home/*`. Absolutely, positively, **do not** try `/home/.*` here. Also, make sure not to accidentally add a space in that path. You should be at least a little afraid wile typing this command, it is a scary command, and you should tripple-check you've entered it correctly (otherwise, you'll be needing that backup).
10. If there are any dot-files or folders in /home, remove them by name. Remember, you must **not** ever run `rm -Rf .*`. That'd match `..`, which means parent directory, ultimately leading to complete filesystem destruction (though some versions of `rm` may refuse to do this, you shouldn't depend on that).
11. Edit `/etc/fstab` and add an entry for your new sda2 partition, like this: `/dev/sda2   /home   ext4   relatime,user_xattr,errors=remount-ro 0 2`. You may use different flags if you like, those are the ones I use. Also, that `pass` number (2) assumes that you've only got two filesystems on sda, which seems very likely since this is sda2.
12. Finally, mount your new home `mount /home`. This should run without errors, and your files should be there. If you get errors, check your fstab line. If you get a warning about files under the mount point being hidden, you didn't delete everything in the last few steps: **unmount `/home`** and delete the remainder. If files are missing, see the first step.

Comment: If you would know please write what happens after removing `/dev/sda1`. I'm afraid because `/home/` is subdirectory of `/`

Comment: @xralf: You don't *remove* sda1, you *resize* it. But of course, you should have backups!

Comment: @derobert I meant "after resizing" when I already have `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` and I decide to remove `/dev/sda1` If my `/home/` directory will be lost or if it will be still on `/dev/sda2`

Comment: @xralf: You copy your home directory to the new filesystem you create on /dev/sda2... I'll edit the post to add instructions.

Comment: I have proposed an edit to your answer to add in the steps for actually moving the files, since @xralf sounds like he/she needs some guidance on that.

Comment: I would bold the words **1. Take a backup.**

Answer (score 4):

Each partition is a separate region of the disk.

If you've left some unpartitioned space, you can create a new partition there with `fdisk`, `cfisk`, `parted` or any other partition manager. Otherwise you'll need to shrink your existing filesystem to make room for the new one. [Today's filesystems do not support shrinking while mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/what-filesystems-can-be-shrunk-online-in-2011)), so you'll need to do that while booting from a live CD/USB (such as the [Parted live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)).

After you've created a separate partition for `/home`:

1. Create a filesystem on it. This operation may be combined with the creation of the partition with some tools.
2. Mount the new filesystem manually to a location that is an empty directory, e.g. `mount /dev/sda2 /media/new_home`.
3. Move your files from `/home` to the new filesystem:

   ```
   mv /home/* /media/new_home
   ```

   You should do that while not logged into your account: either from a root login prompt in text mode, or from a live CD still.
4. Unmount the new filesystem: `umount /media/new_home`
5. Edit the file `/etc/fstab` to add an entry for the new partition. Something like (to go below the entry for `/`):

   ```
   /dev/sda2  /home  ext4  errors=remount-ro,acl  0 2
   ```

   Instead of `/dev/sda2` which could change if you add a second disk, you should use a UUID or a label. See [What happens to partition labels after removing a partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19230/what-happens-to-partition-labels-after-removing-a-partition/19241#19241)
6. If on a live CD, reboot. Otherwise, run `mount /home`.

[What mount points exist on a typical Linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12040/what-mount-points-exist-on-a-typical-linux-system/12086#12086) may be useful background.